# Grep an IP with exact match and match between random string

Tags: string, bash, grep

I'm trying to display the following input file containing IP address. I want to display the exact match between string as shown in example but doesn't seems to success. For demonstration here is example data inside a text file called `input.txt`:

```
1. IP [1.1.1.1] 
2. IP [1.1.1.11] 
3. IP [1.1.1.115]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 " 
5. IP "1.1.1.11 "
6. IP "1.1.1.115"
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@ 
8. IP *JJ1.1.1.11()
9. IP *J@K1.1.1.115U*@ 
10. IP U#@I1.1.1.19lds
```

So, let say I want to find this IP: `1.1.1.1`, I will write the following code:

```
grep -w '1.1.1.1' input.txt
```

With this I got the following output:

```
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
```

But the expected output is, the 7th line also should display because it contains the IP of `1.1.1.1` between a random string. So expected output should be like this:

```
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@
```

And now let say I want to find this string: `1.1.1`:

```
grep -w '1.1.1' input.txt
```

and I got the following output:

```
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
2. IP [1.1.1.11]
3. IP [1.1.1.115]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
5. IP "1.1.1.11 "
6. IP "1.1.1.115"
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@
```

The expected output is, it shouldn't return anything because the whole string `1.1.1` is not inside `input.txt`.

Is grep capable of doing this ?

Comment: yes and it just display the same unexpected output from the 1st line until 7th line. @blurfus

Comment: `grep "\<1.1.1\>" input.txt` also ouput the same result 1st line until 7th line

Comment: I am confused by the question.  You expect this `IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@` to match `1.1.1.1` even though it's not fully a word (i.e. `K1`) but then you expect nothing to match  `1.1.1` with the same input? - what about the same `K1` scenario ?

Comment: If the input has this: `1.1.1-2` it should display because 1.1.1 is there. But if the output is this `1.1.1.3` it shouldn't display. in brief, if a dot or a number after that string 1.1.1 appear it is invalid. Maybe that is what he meant.

Comment: @MaXi32 exactly that is what I meant.

Comment: @blurfus The IP should match between random string. Example of a valid IP between random string is this `UIO@#J1.1.1.1J@` or  `*JKJHH9.1.3.2{}@PO` or `xjk29)192.111.22.3p` or in real log file: `http://1.2.3.4/test?ok` or `http://local/match.php?&abc=1.2.2.2&a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify and be more explicit.

```
$: grep '[^.0-9]1.1.1.1[^.0-9]' txt
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@
```

This is still flawed, though - add another record to your test data.

```
$: grep '[^.0-9]1.1.1.1[^.0-9]' txt
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@
11. IP [1a1b1c1]
```

Then try this:

```
$: grep '[^.0-9]1\.1\.1\.1[^.0-9]' txt
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@
```

This still doesn't account for the possibility of the IP at the very ends of the line, so if that's a possibility at all,

```
$: grep -E '(^|[^.0-9])1\.1\.1\.1([^.0-9]|$)' txt
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@
12. IP 1.1.1.1
```

If IP comes in as a variable, you can quote it in place.

```
$: ip=1.1.1.1
$: echo "grep -E '(^|[^.0-9])${ip//./\\.}([^.0-9]|$)'"
grep -E '(^|[^.0-9])1\.1\.1\.1([^.0-9]|$)'
$: grep -E "(^|[^.0-9])${ip//./\\.}([^.0-9]|$)" txt
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@
12. IP 1.1.1.1
```

This can be problematic if your patterns get complex, but works fine here.

Comment: Thanks, I will add more input and test. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: I like the answer, but what if the input is variable, example ip="1.2.3.2" and then how are we going to modify this variable to have escape like that?. `grep -E '(^|[^.0-9])${ip}([^.0-9]|$)' txt` ? Does it work with variable ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep '[^[:digit:].]1.1.1.1[^[:digit:].]' file
1. IP [1.1.1.1]
4. IP "1.1.1.1 "
7. IP U*@K1.1.1.1-I(M@

$ grep '[^[:digit:].]1.1.1[^[:digit:].]' file
$
```

Comment: Thanks, I will add more input and test. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: I came back to this solution and I think this one is working better including ipv6. Testing some more.

Comment: But it doesn't work if ipv6 end or begin with alphabet like 240e:00f7:4f01:000c:0000:0000:0000:0003:ee